# How to fix terminal when scala interpreter causes invisible text

Tags: scala, terminal, interpreter

sometimes after exiting the scala interpreter I get back to my bash shell and all text is invisible.  Newlines (returns) from input are not displayed.  Below is example output.  The first line is the result of an invisible `pwd` command.  The second line is the output of an invisible `echo` command.

At first I thought this was particular to my machine.  But now it's happened under Fedora+gnome-terminal and Ubuntu+xterm.

Any ideas on why this is happening or how I can fix it?  Presently, I quit the terminal and open a new one.

```
michael@gilguntu:~$ /home/michael
michael@gilguntu:~$ what is going on?
michael@gilguntu:~$ michael@gilguntu:~$ michael@gilguntu:~$ michael@gilguntu:~$ michael@gilguntu:~$ michael@gilguntu:~$ michael@gilguntu:~$ michael@gilguntu:/$
```

Comment: yah, happens on Fedora + Gnome here as well from time to time, usually on OOME where ctrl-C does diddly and I have to kill the process. as @Tomer suggests, reset may do the trick, or just close the terminal window and start up a new one...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just type in "reset". As for why it screws up the terminal... your guess is as good as mine :-)

Comment: P.S. also happens on MacOSX, so it's not a Linux issue, and it happens even on clean exit so it's not a corrupt state due to OOME. Guess it's just what we in the business like to call "a bug".

Comment: Most probably the MacOSX stuff is seriously outdated. Most open source stuff doesn't get updated regularly (or not at all anymore, in case of GPL). Could be possible to try a different jline.jar, but keep in mind that the one shipped with Scala contains special patches.

Comment: Thanks for the "reset" tip, that's been annoying me for ages (on MacOSX).

Comment: The funniest thing is that I've reported an issue in July, 2011. Today its April 2012, the issue is still there (2.9.2-RC2). Way to go, guys.